# How to catch error Connection reset by peer (Errno::ECONNRESET)

Tags: ruby

The following code sometimes generates a "connection reset by peer" error. Can anyone show me how to handle this exception?

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
Connection reset by peer (Errno::ECONNRESET)
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To catch it, do it just like any other exception:

```
begin
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
rescue Errno::ECONNRESET => e
  puts "we are handling it!"
end
```

A more useful pattern is to try a couple of times, then give up:

```
count = 0
begin
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
rescue Errno::ECONNRESET => e
  count += 1
  retry unless count > 10
  puts "tried 10 times and couldn't get #{url}: #{e}
end
```

Comment: More information about this Ruby `retry` pattern: http://blog.mirthlab.com/2012/05/25/cleanly-retrying-blocks-of-code-after-an-exception-in-ruby/

Answer (score 5):

An even more useful pattern is to use the [retries gem](https://github.com/ooyala/retries):

```
with_retries(:max_tries => 5, :rescue => [Errno::ECONNRESET], :max_sleep_seconds => 10) do
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
end
```

Comment: Or the more popular and maintained [retriable](https://github.com/kamui/retriable) gem.