# Ruby to read from a Server that resets frequently

Tags: ruby, sockets

I have a server that disconnects frequently

```
$echo "GET hosts" | nc localhost 323
a.host.com
b.host.com
c.host.com
```

While reading the same thing from ruby with following code

```
s = TCPSocket.new(host,port)
s.puts "GET hosts\n\n\r\r"
data = ""
begin
  until s.closed?
    l = s.gets
    puts "Host:" + l
    data = data + l
  end
rescue Exception => e
  puts "pp" + e.message
end
```

prints out

```
Host:a.host.com
Host:b.host.com
Host:c.host.com
Host:Error reading from 3: Connection reset by peer
```

And the application hangs, somehow.
Any heads up for this?? Weird thing is that it is not entering the exception handler.

Comment: In case of disconnection i want to read all the data which have been read successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You can try rescuing like that `rescue Errno::ECONNRESET => e`.

Check out [How to catch error Connection reset by peer (Errno::ECONNRESET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204920/how-to-catch-error-connection-reset-by-peer-errnoeconnreset), especially the `retry` bit.